# How to prevent flickering when using *ngIf?

Tags: html, angular, angular8

In my **app.component.html**:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <header *ngIf="loggedIn && showHeader"></header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my **app.component.ts**:

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private HeaderService: HeaderService, private AuthService: AuthService) { }

    get loggedIn(): boolean { return this.AuthService.getUserState(); }    
    get showHeader(): boolean { return this.HeaderService.getToggleState(); }
}
```

In my **header.service.ts**:

*We created this service because there are other specific components after login where the header also needs to be hidden.*

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HeaderService {

    showHeader = true;

    constructor() { }

    setToggleState(state: boolean) {
       this.showHeader = state;
    }

    getToggleState() { return this.showHeader; }
}
```

Now, in my `login.component`, the header should be invisible.

What's happening right now, is that there's a brief moment of flicker (seems to happen when you login and then logout, and return to login page) where the header is visible before it's hidden (and yes, also throws up `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`).

What's the best way to achieve this? Should I just set `showHeader` to `false` by default?

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
       // To hide the header
       this.HeaderService.setToggleState(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `*ngIf`, the element is not in the DOM (if the condition is `false`) and will be placed into the DOM in runtime.

Instead, you could use `[hidden]="<your condition>"`, because then your element will be present in the DOM even though the condition is `false`. If then your condition changes to `true`, the elements' `opacity` will be changed from `0` to `1`, which makes the element visible.

Now, in order to get a smoother transition, you can put some CSS on your DOM element like this:

```css
.your-element {
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
```

By that you get a hover-like effect.

Also, for your second problem (short flickering of the header before the data is there): This can be explained because you initialize `showHeader` with `true`. So it shows up at first, then it suddenly disappears when the service is initialized. 
So in that case just set it to `false` at initialization.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.service.setToggleState(true);
  }
```

in login component.
You can set default value to true in service. then when you need to not display the header in which components then set ngoninit to false and ngondestroy to true to avoid flickering.

see here for example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krit8a